# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Hi I installed docker on my ubuntu 14.xx

and whenever I run docker commands, it throws the same error

***docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.***

docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `sudo systemctl start docker` or `sudo service docker start` in order to start the docker daemon, if it's already running type `sudo systemctl status docker` or `sudo service docker status` to see if there are some errors.

Regards.

Comment: thanks! It shows mount: permission denied rmdir : fail to remove 'cpu'

Comment: @BangolPhoenix i guess your user was inside sudo group, or you tried with the root user. This seems to be a very strange error for me, your ubuntu is in a virtual environment? are you able to upgrade to a higher version of ubuntu? what version of docker do you have installed?

Comment: Turned out that my online IDE service was a docker itself!! you were right about the guess when u said it's super strange. They told me it's impossible to install docker cuz its inside of a docker env(though I think I heard there's a way to do that maybe that won't work with this IDE